# Grouping customer orders by date, category and customer with one-hot-encoding result

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing order of customers from different categories (A-F). A one indicates a purchase from this category, wheres a zero indicates none. Now I would like to indicate with 1 and 0 encoding whether a purchase in each respective category was made on a per day and per customer basis.

```
YEAR  MONTH DAY A   B   C   D   E   F   Customer
2007    1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   5000    
2007    1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   5000    
2007    1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   5000    
2007    1   2   0   1   0   0   0   0   5000    
2007    1   2   0   0   1   0   0   0   5000
```

The output should look something like this:

```
 YEAR  MONTH DAY  A     B   C   D   E   F   Customer
 2007   1     1   1     1   0   0   0   0   5000
```

I've been trying to work this out using pandas build in "groupby" however I cant get the right result. Anyone knows how to solve this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html):

```
cols = ['YEAR','MONTH','DAY','Customer']
df = df.groupby(cols, as_index=False).max()
print (df)
   YEAR  MONTH  DAY  Customer  A  B  C  D  E  F
0  2007      1    1      5000  1  1  0  0  0  0
1  2007      1    2      5000  0  1  1  0  0  0
```

Anf if need same order of columns add [`DataFrame.reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html):

```
cols = ['YEAR','MONTH','DAY','Customer']
df = df.groupby(cols, as_index=False).max().reindex_axis(df.columns, axis=1)
print (df)
   YEAR  MONTH  DAY  A  B  C  D  E  F  Customer
0  2007      1    1  1  1  0  0  0  0      5000
1  2007      1    2  0  1  1  0  0  0      5000
```

Comment: works like a charm! Thank you so much! I was not aware of such a good approach!

Comment: Glad can help, nice day!